# Is it possible in Python to add a 'weightage' to distribution plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm working on a project aimed at looking how many quizzes each student takes depending on their school.

My data is set up like this:

```
School No_Tests No_Students
ABC       500      1100
DEF       700      840
GHI       800      590
JKL       400      1350
```

The code I'm using is quite simple, but I'm not sure how to modify it to achieve what I want.

Code:

```
sns.distplot(df['No_Tests'])
```

which displays something like this:

[image]

So I think what this shows is the number of tests on the x-axis, and how often schools with that many tests occur in the data set on the y-axis.

What I'm trying to achieve is similar (maybe needs a different plot?), but essentially I want to be able to add a weightage to *how many* students occur within each group as well (not just the number of schools).

I'm at a loss on how to do this--is it even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Your interpretation of the distribution plot is correct. I wonder if the distribution plot of `No_Tests * No_Students` could achieve what you are trying to convey

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried that but it skewed the plot pretty badly (99% of the data points are in the first 'bin' of the plot, which is probably due to one large school with a lot of students which is throwing it off perhaps).

Comment: I think you can also plot quiz per student on x axis and the density of students on y. Arguably, if you had student-level data, you would be showing the load per student, on a school.level it is an approximation.